# Error - "Use of Unassigned out parameter envelope"

Tags: c#

I am getting an error in below function as "Use of Unassigned out parameter envelope"

```
    public override bool Parse(string input, out Envelope envelope)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        //Load XML from the file into XmlDocument object
        doc.LoadXml(input);

        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode MsgEnvroot = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("MsgEnvelope");
        XmlNode MsgBodyroot = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("MsgBody");

        XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("MsgEnvelope");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            envelope.Priority = node["Priority"].InnerText;
            envelope.RecipientPIMA = node["RecipientPimaAddress"].InnerText;
            envelope.SenderPIMA = node["SenderPimaAddress"].InnerText;
            envelope.EnvelopeDateTime = node["GMT"].InnerText;
        }
        envelope.MsgEnvString = MsgEnvroot.InnerText;
        envelope.MsgBodyString = MsgBodyroot.InnerText;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what the error message says.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `envelope` in the method.

Like

```
public override bool Parse(string input, out Envelope envelope)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    //Load XML from the file into XmlDocument object
    doc.LoadXml(input);

    envelope = new Envelope ();

    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNode MsgEnvroot = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("MsgEnvelope");
    XmlNode MsgBodyroot = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("MsgBody");

    XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("MsgEnvelope");

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        envelope.Priority = node["Priority"].InnerText;
        envelope.RecipientPIMA = node["RecipientPimaAddress"].InnerText;
        envelope.SenderPIMA = node["SenderPimaAddress"].InnerText;
        envelope.EnvelopeDateTime = node["GMT"].InnerText;
    }
    envelope.MsgEnvString = MsgEnvroot.InnerText;
    envelope.MsgBodyString = MsgBodyroot.InnerText;

    return true;
}
```

When we use any out parameter, It is required to initialize or assign that parameter in the method body before exiting from the method.

Answer (score 0):

With [*out* parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you can assume that they are unspecified (not initialised), and you need to assign to it before leaving the context of the method, and prior to using the thing.

So in your case, if the compiler were to let you use `envelope` you would get a `NullReferenceException`. But that isn't to say you can't assign an `out` parameter to be `null` to return to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The `envelope` parameter is an output parameter.  This means that it needs to be assigned to before the routine completes.

You are setting properties on this parameter before it has been established, hence the error message.

If you *really* want an output parameter, you'll need to initialize the envelope parameter before you exit.

```
envelope = new Envelope();
```

However, if you want to alter properties on an existing Envelope object, and you're passing that envelope in as a parameter, you don't actually need it to be an output parameter.

Just change your method signature to:-

```
public override bool Parse(string input, Envelope envelope)
```